# How to get the current _BOOT_ID in journald

Tags: systemd, systemd-journald

How to obtain the current value of **_BOOT_ID** in systemd-journald?

I can do something ugly such like:

```
journalctl -o verbose  --since '2016-05-17' | egrep '^[ ]+_BOOT_ID' | tail -n 1| cut -d"=" -f2
```

Is there a more clever way of do that?

Comment: If you're in fact interested in seeing the journal, not the boot ID, you could use `journalctl -b --since '2016-05-17'` which will give you the log for the current boot starting with that date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```bash
systemd-id128 boot-id
```

From the [man page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-id128.html):

> `systemd-id128` [OPTIONS...] boot-id
>
> With **boot-id**, the identifier of the current boot will be printed.

Answer (score 5):

Alternate method:

```
cat  /proc/sys/kernel/random/boot_id
```

This version contains some dashes. The formatting of the boot ID output by `journalctl` contains no dashes.

The [random(4)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/random.4.html) man page mentions it:

> **/proc interfaces**
>
> The files in the directory */proc/sys/kernel/random* (present since 2.3.16) provide additional information about the */dev/random* device:
>
> *uuid* and *boot_id*
>
> These read-only files contain random strings like 6fd5a44b-35f4-4ad4-a9b9-6b9be13e1fe9.  The former is generated afresh for each read, the latter was generated once.

Comment: Ok, we can use `tr -d '-' < /proc/sys/kernel/random/boot_id` in order to delete dashes.

Answer (score 4):

```sh
journalctl --list-boots | head -1 | cut -d ' ' -f 3
```